# Cakephp 3.9 Application Class not found

Tags: cakephp-3.0

After updating from Cake 3.8 to latest 3.9 my site no longer loads:

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Application' not found in webroot\index.php on line 31
( ! ) Error: Class 'Application' not found in webroot\index.php on line 31.

My src/App;lication.php;

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Application;
use Cake\Http\Server;
    
// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));
    
// Run the request/response through the application
// and emit the response.
$server->emit($server->run());
```

Line 31 is:

new Server(new Application(dirname(**DIR**) . '/config'));

I have tried to debug this and the error comes from the 'new Application'. As far as I can see the way that the Application class is referenced is as it is done elsewhere, in cake.php for example.

I have checked the book for version 3.9 release notes. It seems there are a few other posts on SO reporting similar issues with earlier 3.x versions but none with a proper answer.

Any suggestions as I am totally at a loss.

Comment: Do you have a `src/Application.php` file? That's where this class should be found.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I do yes as I did before running composer updare

Comment: If it works before the composer update, but not afterwards, then maybe the autoloader wasn't dumped properly. Try to redump it (`composer dump-autoload`), ideally in your target environment, and check whether it's being generated properly (ie your class name / namespace exists), and whether the generated files (`vendor/autoload.php`, `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php`) are accessible by PHP.

Comment: running composer dump-autoload: Generated autoload files containing 509 classes...

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project via composer-update and installed all packages as required. I then copied the vendor folder of new project into the old broken project to fix. Problem was in the vendor folder it seems - what the issue was remains a mystery and I am still not clear how the problem was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

The composer.json file needs this section

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
```

to tell Composer to load the App namespace (along with others) into vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php.

Then run composer dump-autoload or composer update.

I had the same problem upgrading from 2.10.24 to 3.9.